# How to format "rake routes"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to make a rake task that outputs the routes in markdown style.

```
|  Prefix Verb   |        URI Pattern        | Controller#Action |
| -------------- | ------------------------- | ----------------- |
|     users GET  | /users(.:format)          | users#index       |
|           POST | /users(.:format)          | users#create      |
|  new_user GET  | /users/new(.:format)      | users#new         |
| edit_user GET  | /users/:id/edit(.:format) | users#edit        |
|      user GET  | /users/:id(.:format)      | users#show        |
```

Is there any way to accomplish this in Rails4?