# Routing error, uninitialized constant Addresses

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this in the view ..

`<%= simple_form_for @addr,  :url => update_path, :method => :post do |f|%>`

I have this in the routes

`post 'update' => 'addresses/update'`

I have this in the controller.

```
def update 
        @addr = Address.new
        @addr = Address.find_by(user_id: spree_current_user.id)
        @addr.update_attributes(getparams)
        @addr.save
    end
```

the thing is instead of making it go the create action, I am trying to make the form submit to the update action

edit:

this is the controllers name

```
AddressesController
```

this is the file name

```
addresses_controller.rb
```

this is the resource

```
resources :addresses
```

Comment: can you post the name and filename of your controller ?

Comment: can you check @Typpex

Comment: Run `rake routes` and make sure update_path exists. I think you need to define your route like this: `post 'update' => 'addresses#update', as: 'update'`

Comment: If you are just trying to update the @addr model, let rails take care of the http method and routing: `<%= simple_form_for @addr do |f|%>`. It will automagically route to create action if @addr is not persisted and to update action if it is persisted already.

Comment: I don't want that to go to create action, because I have some other things there.

Comment: Hey problem with that  update => addresses/update. Thanks :) do you mind writing an answer? @miloshes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `rake routes` and make sure update_path exists. I think you need to define your route like this:

```
post 'update' => 'addresses#update', as: 'update'
```

Comment: My terminal is not showing the routes in a proper format, any quick suggestion to fix it?

Comment: @gates what do you mean by "proper format"? This question might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715385/how-to-format-rake-routes