# How to edit output of "rake routes"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have a problem - how to edit output of command "rake routes"?

I got something like this:

[image]

It is ugly and unreadable. Any ideas how to change this output to more readable?

[EDIT]
It is funny how I got these "minuses", but actually, noone has answered my question. I was asking about how to EDIT/MODIFY output of command "rake routes", not how to edit my terminal to show everything in one line. Of course, this is what I was looking for, partially, but it is not a good answer to my question.

I was looking for something like this:

stackoverflow.com/questions/20715385/how-to-format-rake-routes

but above solution doesnt work, maybe because it is quite old.

**Still, if anyone knows answer to my question, that would be great to get it.**

Comment: Resize your terminal window to have a width of 120 symbols?

Comment: Ofc, but is there any way to change the format of this output? Or do I need to Zoom Out everytime I want to get it readable? I would love to be able to modify the output to show it in a fixed rows and columns, something like this here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715385/how-to-format-rake-routes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried accessing the HTML Routes view?

You can enable it adding this route `get '/rails/info/routes' => 'routes'` in your `config/routes.rb` file and then access the http://localhost:3000/rails/info/routes and you will see something like this:

[image]

Comment: That works, great! I am not sure about marking it as answer, because it is kinda workaround, but you are getting a plus from me. Thanks agian!

Comment: If anybody wants to export this page into a sheet, I've used this JS snippet to copy CSV format into the clipboard:
```copy(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tr.route_row')).map(a => [a.querySelector('td'), a.querySelector('td + td'), a.querySelector('[data-route-path]'), a.querySelector('p')]).map(td => [td[0].innerText, td[1].innerText, td[2].innerText, td[3].innerText]).join('\n'))```

Answer (score 4):

### Rails 6+

This is how you can edit the output of the command `rails routes` in the terminal.

Rails 6 introduced `--expanded` option.

Here is an example:

```
$ rails routes --expanded
--[ Route 1 ]------------------------------------------------------------
Prefix            | high_scores
Verb              | GET
URI               | /high_scores(.:format)
Controller#Action | high_scores#index
--[ Route 2 ]------------------------------------------------------------
Prefix            | new_high_score
Verb              | GET
URI               | /high_scores/new(.:format)
Controller#Action | high_scores#new
--[ Route 3 ]------------------------------------------------------------
Prefix            | blog
Verb              |
URI               | /blog
Controller#Action | Blog::Engine

[ Routes for Blog::Engine ]
--[ Route 1 ]------------------------------------------------------------
Prefix            | cart
Verb              | GET
URI               | /cart(.:format)
Controller#Action | cart#show
```

And a [link to PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/32130).

Answer (score 2):

You can grep your routes from the command line, like this:

For example, if you're looking for any route involving the word 'foobar'

`rake routes | grep foobar`

This is great if you just want quick output from the command line.

Here's a guide to GREP that I learned a lot from: https://www.maketecheasier.com/beginners-guide-to-grep/